# How well does AngularJS now work with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am asking this question as I know both AngularJS and Typescript have been changing very much over the last year and it's hard to keep up.

What I would like to know is how easy is it for me to now start integrating Typescript into my AngularJS projects. Are there any good examples out there that could get me started.

Also with the AngularJS 2.0 and its use of ECMAScript 6 will typescript even be needed or will ECMAScript 6 do much of the same thing as typescript ?

Comment: Other than to say that others have used TypeScript to create an Angular based web application, the rest of your question seems to be all opinion, and not a great fit for a StackOverflow as written. Do you have a specific programming question related to Angular and TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code generation features (classes / modules etc) are not the main selling feature of TypeScript. The feature is TypeSafety. This will not be provided by ES 6 and therefore typescript is still relevant.

Angular + TypeScript work really well together. Here is a demo : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-6vT7xgE4Y&hd=1